# AWS deploying client server application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, client-server, virtual-machine

I have a question regarding this AWS virtual machine. I already setup all TCP, UDP, Traffic, and ICMP from anywhere on the Security Group and my local machine can ping the virtual machine to the public IP address. but somehow, if i try to use the client server connection from my local machine the socket class cannot connect to the other class on the virtual machine?
This is the client code on local machine:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(VMAdress, 6789); DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); sentence = inFromUser.readLine(); outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n'); modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
```

This is the Server code on virtual machine:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

     while(true)
     {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
     }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Detail and clarity are needed. Are you trying to connect to the server from your local machine or from the server to itself?  What is the error you receive?  Have you tested the connection with simple tools like `nc remote-addr remote-port`?

Comment: Hallo, I try to create a connection between two classes. one class as a server and the other one as the client. the client class will run on the local machine and the other one on the virtual machine. The error is: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Connection timed out will usually be a network device blocking the traffic -- either the security group on the target, **or** your local network's firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have already try with 2 VM on the same security group but some how it still get the same error msg, Do i have to set both of them on the same subnet?

Comment: No, they do not need to be on the same subnet, but inside AWS you should use the private IP address of the instances when establishing internal connections.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Thx for the reply. I already try with the private IP and still not working... but when i use the same ip adress on the CMD to ping, it work just fine...